# Opening a Web View

Tags: android, webview, imagebutton

I have an image button that when clicked opens a new activity with a web view in.  The web view will display some custom HTML.  When I click the button the web view displays nothing.

This is the code for my button view:-

```
    public void GoToContact(View view)  
{

        WebView webView;

        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1></body></html>";
           webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");

}
```

THIS IS MY WEB VIEW LAYOUT:-

```
    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">



    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/GoToHome"
    android:onClick="GoToTC" 
    android:background="@drawable/test"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/header"/>

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you post your layout too?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }

        });

    }

}


public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare WebView as class member of your activity:

```
    WebView webView;

    public void GoToContact(View view)  
    {

    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1></body></html>";
       webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");

   }
```

then try it again...
btw please show us your layout.xml and the code of the whole activity class.